# flexbox row gap inconsistent on dynamically sized divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `flex` container that contains dynamically generated items. These items can be of different heights every time the page is regenerated and - as a result - the spacing between the items is always different.

While each item's distance to its siblings should be a constant `20px` (on all sides), if one of its siblings is larger or smaller, the gap between them increases.

*Without targeting every single element* and manually adjusting their position, is there a way I can ensure that each item has exactly 20px between it and its siblings? [**Like this**](https://jsfiddle.net/bf8cuj1g/1/).

```css
/* Important CSS */
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    row-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

.item{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

/* Dont worry about this bit */
.container{
    width: 600px;
}
/* To emulate dynamically generated content */
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(6){
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a work for `grid`'s masonry layout. But it's not supported on all browsers (It only works on Mozilla Firefox currently). But a workaround you could use is by using the `column-count` property. See the snippet below:

```css
/* Important CSS */

.container {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.item {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  break-inside: avoid;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}


/* Dont worry about this bit */

.container {
  width: 600px;
}


/* To emulate dynamically generated content */

.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

More on it on [this website](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/).